# understanding the following regex

Tags: php, regex

I wrote a regex, but it doesn't work as i expect. Take a look please

---

```
preg_match_all("/([\.\:]?)(.{0,65}?[^\s]*".preg_quote($word)."[^\s]*.{0,65})/siu",$content,$matched);
```

`[^\s]*".preg_quote($word)."[^\s]`//

this part match the whole word, if it contain the keyword, for example it match **keyword** if i search for **wor** keyword.

`.{0,65}?[^\s]*".preg_quote($word)."[^\s]*.{0,65}`

here i get up to 65 characters before and after the keyword, ie. i will get

many words here **keyword** and other words here

---

And now, what is the problem. I try to match the sentence from the begining, if there is any of [.:] characters within {65} characters

if i have sach structure - word1 word2 **.** {less then 65 character here} keyword {other characters here}

i expect, then if i wrote `([\.\:]?)(.{0,65}?[^\s]*".preg_quote($word)."[^\s]*.{0,65})`

it will match `.{less then 65 character here} keyword {65 characters}`

but it doesn't. the part `[\.\:]?` hasn't any influence on regex. it match all {65} characters.

**i need to match sentence from begining, if the start of sentence within 65 characters before the keyword**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[.:]?` means "match a dot (`.`), a colon (`:`), or nothing"; if the next character is not a dot or colon, `([.:]?)` matches nothing.  Then `.{0,65}` matches up to 65 of anything, *including `.` or `:`*.  I think this is what you're looking for:

```
$source='A regular expression (regex or regexp for short) is a special text string for describing a search pattern. You can think of regular expressions as wildcards on steroids.';
$word = 'regular';
preg_match_all('#[^.:]{0,65}\b'.preg_quote($word).'\b.{0,65}#siu', $source, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

output:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
      [0] => A regular expression (regex or regexp for short) is a special text string 
      [1] =>  You can think of regular expressions as wildcards on steroids.
    )

)
```

(See it live on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/Q3Dok))

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace the fist

```
.{0,65}
```

by

```
[^\.\:]{0,65}
```

After all, It may be looked like

```
preg_match_all("/([^\.\:]{0,65}?[^\s]*".preg_quote($word)."[^\s]*.{0,65})/siu",$content,$matched);
```